# Google Alerts with site filters never return results, but normal searches do

Tags: google-search, google-alerts

I've got a few of Google Alerts set up based on a site. The alerts are set to "All results" (and not "Only the best results"). For example:

```
password dump site:pastebin.com
```

I use the above to track data breaches and collect passwords for my password lists.

"I use" is a misnomer because I've never gotten an alert even though there are lots of hits when searching. I've got similar alerts for different sites (like the National Science Foundation, `nsf.gov`) and they have never fired either.

How do I set up an alert with a site filter?

Comment: Do you have any successful alerts without specifying the site?

Comment: Yes, I have daily alerts for those that don't specify the site filter.

Comment: Have you tried setting up an alert with notify as it happens on site:superuser.com or even better a Google site since I'm sure they keep those indexes up to date?  I think you should see an alert pretty quickly.  (Just trying to think through a simple test.)

Comment: If I recall, Google recently had an issue where alerts just weren't happening for a lot of people for *months*. This was supposedly fixed. Could you have been caught up in that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Google search operator such as `inurl:subject.com` which will search the URL or `intext:subject.com passwords` which will search all text on the Internet for that string.

Answer (score 0):

Google Alerts tends to report new search results and not updates to existing results. You may want to [experiment with page2rss.com](http://page2rss.com/), which allows you to track changes on specific web page(s).

You could then filter the emails &/or feeds from page2rss by keywords within your client.

Comment: Watch out, that link seems dead/redirects to a malware site.